How to store diffs of huge zip files instead of full updated zip files
Every 12 months, I use Google Takeout (and similar services for other platforms) to do exports of my data.
Google unfortunately does not let me export a "diff" from what I downloaded last time.
So I need to re-download the whole thing, which is hundreds of gigabytes.
And Google chunks the export into zip files with a 50 GB max.
On my home PC, I have a folder called "backups", which has folders for each year ("2024", "2023", "2022", and so on).
Within those year folders, I have backups in massive 50 GB zip files.
I'd love if I could minimize disk space used and take advantage of the fact that more recent backups contain mostly the same information as older ones.
Maybe use some sort of diff system.
Is there some way I could store the original zip files plus the diffs to the newer ones and delete the newer ones?
(If I ever wanted to restore, I'd be able to recreate the newer zip files later, using the original zip files + the diffs.)
